# 16.04 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS upgrade: dock configuration

Tags: 18.04, configuration, ubuntu-dock

In 16.04 LTS, an icon for an attached device appeared automatically in the dock. In 18.04.1 LTS the icon is on the main screen, buried under opened windows.

I can't drag the icons over to the dock and can't find any instructions on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour has changed indeed. The concept behind how this works in Gnome Shell is that you access and manage these devices through Files (aka nautilus file manager). As such, your drive is two clicks away rather than one. While you are at work, extra similarly looking drive icons are not cluttering your workspace. They are listed in the left pane of Files, where you can unmount/mount them or remove them. The left dock is solely used for launching applications and managing running applications.

While Gnome Shell moves away from an active desktop, and by default works with a desktop which only functions as a background without icons, Ubuntu still maintains the active desktop. Your drive icons appear there, but that can be turned off in Tweaks, "Desktop" tab.